# WP Rig: Error running npm run build: Cannot find "/vendor/bin/phpcs"

Tags: npm, gulp, phpcs

I've installed [WP Rig](https://wprig.mor10.com/) on a Windows development machine running WAMPserver.

I get to Step 5 at the URL above where I need to run `npm run build`, and then I receive an error:

> ```
> Finished 'images' after 1.91 s
> [16:34:30] 'php' errored after 5.92 s
> [16:34:30] Error in plugin "gulp-phpcs"
> Message:
>     Cannot find "C:\wamp64\www\wprig.local\wp-content\themes\wprig-master/vendor/bin/phpcs"[16:34:30] 'buildDev' errored after 5.94 s
> ```

So, I installed phpcs by navigating to `/wp-content/themes/wprig-master`, and running:

```
npm install gulp-phpcs --save-dev
```

Then edited `composer.json` to replace;

```
"phpcs-dev": "\"vendors/phpcs\"",
```

with;

```
"phpcs-dev": "\"node_modules/gulp-phpcs\"",
```

The folder `C:\wamp64\www\wprig.local\wp-content\themes\wprig-master/vendor/gulp-phpcs` now exists.

It contains:

[image]

But I still receive the following error when I run `npm run build`:

> ```
> Message:
>     Cannot find "C:\wamp64\www\wprig.local\wp-content\themes\wprig-master/node_modules/gulp-phpcs"`
> ```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revert changes to `composer.json` file relating with the custom `phpcs-dev` script.

Your `composer.json` should have phpcs-dev script to be:

```
    "phpcs-dev": "\"vendor/bin/phpcs\"",
```

https://github.com/wprig/wprig/blob/v2.0.1/composer.json#L32

And not

```
     "phpcs-dev": "\"vendors/phpcs\"",
```

Then, run

```
 composer install
```

Test that `phpcs-dev` runs successfully by running:

```
 composer phpcs-dev
```

After taking care that the PHP dependencies are all set up the right way, proceed to installing the Javascript dependencies for WPRig by running:

```
npm install
```

Comment: Thank you Oluwafemi, I complete the steps above, and then run `npm run build` again, but I receive a similar error: `'php' errored after 24 s
[15:12:18] Error in plugin "gulp-phpcs"
Message:
    Cannot find "C:\wamp64\www\wprig.local\wp-content\themes\wprig-master/node_modules/gulp-phpcs"`

Comment: I started a fresh development site to get rid of my hacks, and `npm run build` runs without error. Thank you *so* much Olu.